# Timer ends = application crash

Tags: android, timer, crash

I need to make every second the health to go down by "1" after going the health under 20 or is equal to 20 to show the "alertDialog" i don't have any errors in the code. The problem is crushing after the "Health" passed the border/limit the application is crushing, i don't know why is that happening, is there someone to help me with it ?
I also make sure that there is one time show of the "alertDialog" with boolean but doesn't help...
Thanks in advice :)

Code:

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Health -= 1;
                if (Health <= 20) {
                    if (!canSeeWarnDialog) {
                        final AlertDialog alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                MainActivity.this).create();
                        alertDialog2.setTitle("Im hungry");
                        alertDialog2.setMessage("The dog health is going low "
                                + "\ngive him some food");
                        alertDialog2.setButton("Got it",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        alertDialog2.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                        alertDialog2.show();
                        canSeeWarnDialog = true;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 1000, 1000);//TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
```

Comment: You cannot show dialogs from an non-UI thread afaik. Use a different method (probably: [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)) or do the show stuff in a separate runnable started via `runOnUiThread`.

Comment: dst probably has the right answer.  But please never come here asking about a crash without posting the stacktrace from the logcat-  we're rarely going to solve it without that.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) ? It seems more suitable to your task and it handles all the callbacks on the UI thread for you.

Comment: after end it will start automatically from the beginning ?
and also still is crushing :/

Comment: is there some person which can help me to make a really simple timer/Handler or anything, which the health will go down by "1" and when the health will go 20 or under 20 to show the alertDialog or turn the phone alarm or to do anything to inform the player ? Thanks :)

Comment: @Stefan, the CountDownTimer doesn't restart automatically. You can recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a CountDownTimer.
When taking "length" as amount of Health in miliseconds
 (*1000 -> 30 max health => 30000 length).Current health should be millisUntilFinished/1000.

```
boolean notified = false;
new CountDownTimer(length, 1000) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
    {
      if(millisUntilFinished <= 20 && !notified)
      {
         final AlertDialog alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            MainActivity.this).create();
                    alertDialog2.setTitle("Im hungry");
                    alertDialog2.setMessage("The dog health is going low "
                            + "\ngive him some food");
                    alertDialog2.setButton("Got it",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    alertDialog2.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog2.show();
                    notified = true;
      }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() 
    {
      //Health is 0.
      notified = false; // For next time.
      //if you want to restart -> retrieve full health:
      this.start();
    }
};
```

Comment: I dont get this with if you want to restart ? i just need to put `Health = 100;` ?

Comment: My suggestion would be to use millisUntilFinished as the Health. and raising Health to 100 means restarting the Timer. or this.start();

Comment: oh i get it, but i don't really need that i need when the health is 20 or lower than you need to feed the "dog" and health to be greater than 20 but the timer still to count till the Health goes 0 to dog to die ... Hope you understand me :)
EDIT: and also i want this action to go on every 2 minutes...